# Is any authentication required when we use neo4j REST API from sharepoint 2013?

Tags: neo4j, sharepoint-2013

We want to retrieve data from neo4j database using REST API from SharePoint page. Is there any authentication required for that like any tokens ? am new to neo4j world.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would generally want to ensure that your neo4j server has authentication enabled. [Here is the dev manual section](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/) covering authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thank you so much!!